# Where can “porosimetry” be hyphenated?

Tags: spelling, hyphens

Where can I hyphenate (split at the end of the line; British English) the word `porosimetry`? [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porosimetry) and [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/porosimetry) do not know the word at all and [ushuaia](http://www.ushuaia.pl/hyphen/?ln=en) hyphenates only at one position: `porosi•metry` (GB; for US English: `porosime•try`). I have seen  `poros•imetry` printed, which is not in accordance with my pronunciation of the word, but possibly I got that wrong because I am no native speaker but an ELL. (Even for `porosity` I found different hyphenation patterns in different dictionaries.)

Comment: Thanks to the abundance of vowels, you could safely hyphenate it after either *o*, the *i* (as shown), the *m* (as shown), or even the *e* without confusing the reader in the least. It's not a word one uses in everyday speech, so it's doubtful anyone would challenge your publisher for breaking the word at any point that is needed for space that still makes sense. The so-called *rules* for hyphenation are somewhat, uhm,  *flexible* in the history of English printing, to say the least. Follow a dictionary source for common words, but create your own preference(s) in this case.

Comment: Also, read this entry on EL&U if you are interested in longer answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line The answer by @Peter Shor is especially useful. If Mr. Shor disagrees with my comment above, I'll take it down and defer to him.

Comment: For what it's worth, even highly literate native speakers are likely to mispronounce this word and struggle with hyphenating it appropriately.

Comment: Merriam-Webster does know porosimeter though, which as @MarkHubbard has pointed out has a lot of possible places to hyphenate: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porosimeter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to figure out the pronunciation of *porosimetry*.

The pronunciation appears to be /pɔːrɒˈsɪmɪtri/, so the hyphenation is po-ro-sim-e-try, where we hyphenate after *sim* because the rule is to avoid hyphenating after a short vowel in a stressed syllable.

I know how to pronounce *porosity* /pɔːˈrɒsɪti/, so the hyphenation is *po-ros-i-ty*. Notice the disagreement with the hyphenation of *porosimetry.* This occurs because different syllables are stressed.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible hyphenation break points as per comments

> po-rosimetry
>   poro-simetry
>   porosi-metry
>   porosim-etry
>   porosime-try